# SharePoint 2007: Drop Down with Image Button

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, development, 2007, jquery

I have been asked if I can add a few images on our company's SharePoint site, which on mouse-over or on-click should drop-down a list of menu items.

Is this possible in SharePoint foundation?

Answer (score 1):

create a new JavaScript file, add jquery code for dropdown menu, save JavaScript in styles library,add a content editor web part on your page and reference your JavaScript file.